# Troubleshoot broken ZFS

Tags: server, data-recovery, troubleshooting, zfs

I have one zpool called **tank** in RaidZ1 with 5x1TB SATA HDDs. I'm using Ubuntu Server 11.10 Oneric, kernel 3.0.0-15-server. Installed ZFS from [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/daily) also I'm using zfs-auto-snapshot. The ZFS file system when zfs module loaded to the kernel hangs my computer. 
Before it I created few new file systems:

```
zfs create -V 10G tank/iscsi1
zfs create -V 10G tank/iscsi2
zfs create -V 10G tank/iscsi3
```

I shared them through iSCSI by /dev/tank/iscsiX path. And my computer started to hanging sometimes when I used tank/iscsiX by iSCSI, do not know why exactly. I switched off iSCSI and started to remove this file systems:

```
zfs destroy tank/iscsi3
```

I'm also using **zfs-auto-snapshot** so I had snapshots and without **-r** key my command not destroying the FS. So I issued next command:

```
zfs destroy tank/iscsi3 -r
```

The **tank/iscsi3** FS was clean and contain nothing - it was destroyed without an issue.
But **tank/iscsi2** and **tank/iscsi1** contained a lot of information. I tried

```
zfs destroy tank/iscsi2 -r
```

After some time my computer hang out. I rebooted computer. It didn't boot very fast, HDDs starts working like a crazy making a lot of noise, after 15 minutes HDDs stopped go crazy and OS booted at last. All seems to be ok - **tank/iscsi2** was destroyed. After file systems at the **tank** was accessible, `zpool status` showed no corruption.
I issued new command:

```
zfs destroy tank/iscsi1 -r
```

/*
Situation was repeated - after some time my computer hang out. But this time ZFS seams not to healed itself. After computer switched on it started to work: loading scripts and kernel modules, after zfs starting to work it hanging my computer.
*/

Situation changed. Now computer hags two minutes after boot. So now I can see the content of zfs pool. But I can't stop hanging after 2 minutes.

I need to recover else ZFS file systems which lying in the same zpool.
`zpool scrub tank` not helps. PC hanging in a 2 minutes after the boot.
Few month ago I backup OS to flash drive. Booting from backed-up OS and import have the same results - OS starts hanging.
How to recover my data at ZFS tank?

[Error message2 http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/7652/img1437ny.jpg](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/7652/img1437ny.jpg)
[Error message3 http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/9360/img1438s.jpg](http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/9360/img1438s.jpg)

Comment: I would try to export and then import the pool

Comment: I told: I did it before and not once and not in one operation system. But it is not helping.

Comment: Did you try scrubbing that thing up?

Comment: I did not, but I will try.

Comment: `zpool scrub tank` not helps. PC hanging in a 2 minutes after the boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
zpool export tank
set zfs:zfs_recover=1
zdb -e -bcsvL tank
zpool import tank -f
```

by [this](http://sigtar.com/2009/10/19/opensolaris-zfs-recovery-after-kernel-panic/) article.

Looks like `zpool scrub tank` not helped, but I executed this command and at list everything working now, so I do not know exactly.

Comment: when you ran the zdb -e -bcsvL command how long did it take? How big was your pool and did you utilize deduplication?

Comment: I'm utilizing dedup, the pool was about 5 TiB and occupied space was 2 TiB. The fixing ZFS took about two days in my case.

Comment: It helped me alot