# How to blacklist zfs kernel module during boot?

Tags: 14.04, grub2, kernel, zfs

How to disable ZFS kernel-module before boot in grub?

It is mentioned that some modules can be disabled through grub command line in similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/110349/34897). Unfortunately this method is not working with zfs:

```
module_to_blacklist.blacklist=yes
```

With next message: *unknown parameter 'blacklist' ignored*

Comment: Hello BBK, would be nice to know why you are trying to do this. There might be alternatives to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately zfs some times need to be restored. When Ubuntu booted with zfs module it trying to load damaged zpool so in the end it hangs. I need to load the system without zfs, only then I'm able to restore zfs. [This method](http://askubuntu.com/a/146263/34897) for recovery is working well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Troubleshoot broken ZFS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142857/troubleshoot-broken-zfs)

Comment: @ElderGeek this is not a dupe. The OP wants to blacklist a specific module, not troubleshoot one.

Comment: @terdon Vote retracted

Comment: @terdon You'll note that the OP references the very question I pointed at in the comment above.

Comment: Did you install ZFS via DKMS? Perhaps from here? https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct that you installed ZFS via dkms then it looks like you need to remove it via the same tool.

`dkms remove [module/module-version] [-k kernel/arch] [--all]`

```
       Removes a module/version or module/version/kernel/arch  combination
       from  the  tree.   If  the  module is currently installed, it first
       uninstalls  it  and  if  applicable,  will  replace  it  with   its
       original_module.   Use  the  --all  option  in  order to remove all
       instances for every kernel at once.
```

Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/dkms.8.html

**Note:** You might wish to avoid using the --all option until you are certain that you have obtained the desired results.

Comment: Is there a way to disable it from grub loader before OS boot?

Comment: **It looks like you can disable zfs from grub** by removing "boot=zfs" or "boot=zfs rpool=rpool bootfs=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu" from your grub config whichever line is next to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX and updating grub.     Source:https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-14.04-or-Later-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this issue because I want to boot a recent Ubuntu Live CD such that the kernel is not tainted. However the ZFS modules taint the kernel.

**TLDR;** Booting with the kernel parameter `systemd.mask=zfs.target` allowed booting without loading the zfs modules automatically.

In investigating this I found 3 places where the zfs module could get loaded.

1. Initrd

   - The file `/scripts/zfs` tries to load the module in load_module_initrd, but this only gets called if there is a kernel parameter `boot=zfs`
2. init.d

   - The script `/etc/init.d/zfs-import` will load the module when started, but this init script is by default only started at run levels `S` (single user mode), so not normally.
3. systemd

   - The target `zfs.target`, which is started by the `multi-user.target`, will load the modules via the `zfs-load-module.service`. This can be disabled with the kernel boot parameter `systemd.mask=zfs.target`